# Ruby + Sinatra + Sequel, cannot load pg_ext

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm writing app using Ruby, Sinatra, psql and Sequel. I'm on Windows 7. I created database and wrote migations following tutorial. Now I should run them using

```
sequel -m migrations postgres://<username>:<password>@localhost/good_vids_development
```

but I'm getting an error `AdapterNotFound, Load Error, cannot load such file: pg_ext.`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the pg gem's C extension was not compiled.  You either need to fix that or use a pure ruby driver (e.g. jeremyevans-postgres-pr).